# hiding header smoothly (like in twitter app)

Tags: android

I have listView like main part of my activity view. I want to implement header bar like in twitter app. (hiding header onScroll UP and showing header onScroll DOWN). How can I do this?

Thanks for all future help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [PoppyView](https://github.com/flavienlaurent/poppyview) though you may need to tweak it to implement it as per your requirement